# Is there a way to monitor javascript functions running on a page?

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there a way to see which functions are being executed on a page?

If I load an external script on a page, is it possible to change what a function does on the fly or prevent it from running?

Comment: You can use your browser's developer tools.

Comment: In practice this wouldn't be very useful, as there are often thousands of functions executing per second when things are actually happening.

Comment: https://www.codeschool.com/courses/discover-devtools is a free course about the developer tools in chrome.  I think they're the best compared to other popular browsers, but it is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded, so you cannot run other JS code *in parallel* to monitor other JS code. You'd need access to the engine if you wanted change its behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#establish-script-block-source) introduces [`onbeforescriptexecute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/beforescriptexecute) event, which you can use to detect new scripts on the fly, and block them if you want.

For example:

```
window.addEventListener('beforescriptexecute', function(e) {
    // e.target.src is the URL of the external loaded script
    // e.target.innerHTML is the content of the inline loaded script
    if (e.target.src === urlToBlock)
        e.preventDefault(); // Block script
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebug for Firefox or Chrome Developer Tools. You can set the breakpoints and debug your code very well.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging Here's a good place to start.